# How to loop over a binary file in Python in chunks

Tags: python, binary-data

I'm trying to use Python to loop over a long binary file filled with 8-byte records.

Each record has the format `[ uint16 | uint16 | uint32 ]`
*(which is `"HHI"` in struct-formatting)*

Apparently each 8-byte block is getting treated as an `int`, instead of an array of 8-bytes, then causing the `struct.unpack` call to fail

```
with open(fname, "rb") as f:
    sz=struct.calcsize("HHI")
    print(sz)                # This shows 8, as expected 
    for raw in f.read(sz):   # Expect this should read 8 bytes into raw
        print(type(raw))     # This says raw is an 'int', not a byte-array
        record=struct.unpack("HHI", raw ) # "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'"
        print(record)
```

How can I read my file as a series of structures, and print them each out?

Comment: I think `f.read(len)` is not iterable

Comment: Don't you just want `raw = f.read(len)`?  This gives you all eight bytes at once, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Mostly, yes:   I want the first 8bytes, then iterate to get the next 8, and the following 8, etc, until the full file has been processed.

Answer (score 4):

The [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) builtin, if passed a callable and a sentinel value will call the callable repeatedly until the sentinel value is returned.

So you can create a partial function with [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) (or use a `lambda`) and pass it to `iter`, like this:

```
with open('foo.bin', 'rb') as f:
    chunker = functools.partial(f.read, 8)
    for chunk in iter(chunker, b''):      # Read 8 byte chunks until empty byte returned
        # Do stuff with chunk
```

Answer (score 3):

`f.read(len)` only returns a byte string. Then `raw` will be a single byte.

The correct way of looping is:

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        raw = f.read(8)
        if len(raw)!=8:
            break # ignore the incomplete "record" if any
        record = struct.unpack("HHI", raw )
        print(record)
```

Comment: What if there are exactly 8 bytes in the final chunk?

Comment: @Rimer It will be processed as normal and break in the next iteration. This question specified that we are reading "a long binary file filled with 8-byte records..."

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this before, but it looks like an initialization issue:

```
   with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        fmt = 'HHI'
        raw=struct.pack(fmt,1,2,3)
        len=struct.calcsize(fmt)
        print(len)               # This shows 8, as expected 
        for raw in f.read(len):  # Expect this should read 8 bytes into raw
            print(type(raw))     # This says raw is an 'int', not a byte-array
            record=struct.unpack(fmt, raw ) # "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'"
            print(record)
```

You may want to look at iter_unpack() for optimization if you have adequate ram.

Note that in 3.7, the default value changes from bytes to string. see near end of page https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack